# Android Studio: Two projects in a single window

Tags: android, android-studio, window, project

I have to move my Eclipse project to Android Studio (2.1.2) but apart from a couple of errors while importing (that's a different problem for now) I noticed that each project gets its own window. I already googled and used the search funktion here on stackexchange but only found threads about it that are more than two years old.

Is it possible to keep every project in a single window (like it is in Ecliupse) yet, so you can easily compare files without changing the window?

Comment: Yes,  its totally possible using multi-modules setup , please see this helpful article for the basics and more, https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does this mean that you can still only add modules, not have two or more more or less independent and full projects in the same window though?